# R: Sub-selecting through XTS object vs Matrix: Why such a performance hit?

Tags: r, performance, xts

Subselecting in a for loop over an equal sized XTS object vs an R matrix yields vastly difference performances.  In the following example on my machine the matrix code takes 0.42 seconds, while the XTS code takes 31.64 seconds.  Assuming I must do a loop like this, should I pre-convert all my XTS objects using as.matrix prior, or is there a way to get higher performance from the xts object?

```
library(xts)

NumRows <- 1000000
NumCols <- 30
theMatrix <- matrix(rep(1,NumRows*NumCols),nrow=NumRows)
theXTS <- xts(theMatrix,Sys.Date()+1:NumRows)

system.time({  

  for(k in 1:NumRows){
    DataPoint <- theMatrix[k,1]
  }

})

system.time({  

  for(k in 1:NumRows){
    DataPoint <- theXTS[k,1]
  }

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  The short answer is that when you subset an xts object you're extracting the relevant times from a vector, and also extracting the relevant rows from the matrix which is more expensive in computational time than simply extracting the components from the matrix alone.  You typically want to keep your data in xts format in order to make subsetting your data via times easy, but you can call `coredata` first (which is faster than `as.matrix`), which exposes the matrix of data,  before subsetting an `xts` object via integer indices

Read `?coredata`

```
> class(coredata(theXTS))
[1] "matrix"

# Compare benchmark below against subsetting with an existing matrix
theXTS_matrix <- as.matrix(theXTS)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(theXTS_matrix[5, 7:10], coredata(theXTS), 

coredata(theXTS)[5, 7:10],
                   theXTS[5, 7:10], as.matrix(theXTS)[5, 7:10])
# Unit: nanoseconds
# expr    min       lq      mean   median       uq    max neval
# theXTS_matrix[5, 7:10]    663   1087.5   1479.39   1254.0   1569.0   9062   100
# coredata(theXTS)  10456  12090.5  13413.92  13122.0  14269.0  24106   100
# coredata(theXTS)[5, 7:10]  11703  12959.5  15193.21  14298.5  15499.5  56137   100
# theXTS[5, 7:10]  27519  30293.5  32669.63  31805.5  33130.5  57130   100
# as.matrix(theXTS)[5, 7:10] 200927 205187.5 209949.47 206926.0 212582.0 330426   100
```

i.e. `coredata` offers a small overhead, but the subsetting is then faster.

Answer (score 2):

[FXQuantTrader's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39419863/271616) provides a couple good points, but they don't explain the size of the difference between the two functions. I'd also note that there's no "searching" being done in the question: `i` and `j` are already integers, so it's just a direct indexing operation.

Most of the difference in speed can be attributed to all the checks that are done in `[.xts`. Even without those, you should expect `[.xts` to be marginally slower than `[` on a matrix, since xts objects always need to do an extra operation: subsetting the index.

```
R> system.time(for(k in 1:10000) theMatrix[k, 1:10])
   user  system elapsed 
  0.012   0.000   0.015 
R> system.time(for(k in 1:10000)
+   .Call('_do_subset_xts', theXTS, k, 1:10, F, PACKAGE='xts'))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.016   0.000   0.018
```